# Class 'WC_Session' not found in class-wc-session-handler.php

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies, woocommerce

I have plugin `"Woocommerce Email Cart"` and it was running fine on `Woocommerce 2.2`. When I upgrade that to `Woocommerce 2.5.2` I got this few errors including this. I fixed the other issues but I'm unable to fix this.
I got error saying:-

> Fatal error: Class 'WC_Session' not found in
>   /home/31776xa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-session-handler.php
>   on line 18

```
$woocommerce->frontend_includes();
$session_class = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_session_handler', 'WC_Session_Handler' );
$woocommerce->session  = new $session_class();
$woocommerce->cart     = new WC_Cart();  
$woocommerce->customer = new WC_Customer();
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-on-user-profile-class-wc_session-not-found     and   https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warnings-and-errors-locked-out-of-my-site-please-help

Comment: Sorry, but there is no solution in those links